# How do I get Gajim to show up in Unity's system tray?

Tags: unity, indicator

I know how to whitelist most other applications, but adding 'Gajim' and 'gajim' doesn't seem to work.

Does it have an appindicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it'd be a better idea to install "Ubuntu Ayanta Integration" or a similar plugin instead.  See http://trac-plugins.gajim.org/wiki/UbuntuIntegrationPlugin for instance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a strange twist, killing Gajim and restarting it seems to have worked.

Apparently the correct value is `Gajim`.